# Textarea text to table cell doesnt carry over carriage returns

Tags: javascript

I need your help,

How can I make a textarea such that, at the click of a button would move display text in a textarea with carriage returns in a table cell? The way it is now, it just combines it all into 1 line in the table cell.The alert box respects the carriage returns.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){

var x = document.getElementById('comments').value

var y = '<table><tr><td>'+x+'</td></tr></table>'

document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML = y

//alert(x)

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="tbl"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `<textarea>` box carriage returns are visible, but carriage returns are ignored in HTML.  They need to be converted to `<br>` tags.

Use `.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');` to convert carriage returns to `<br>` tags

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/d5PBQ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function test(){
    var x, y; 
    x = document.getElementById('comments').value.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    y = '<table><tr><td>'+x+'</td></tr></table>'
    document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML = y

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tbl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Textarea line breaks are not the same as HTML line breaks.

```
var text = document.getElementById('comments').value;
text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Using the above will convert the breaks to standard HTML line breaks `<br/>`.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function test(){

      var x = document.getElementById('comments').value;
          x = x.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
      var y = '<table><tr><td>'+x+'</td></tr></table>';

      document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML = y;

   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="tbl"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```css
#tbl {white-space:pre-wrap}
```

This will preserve all whitespace, which means you can enter multiple spaces and it will work. Newlines will work. Really long lines will be wrapped. In fact, it behaves pretty much exactly like a textarea. Neat!